# (When) are HandleScopes (still) necessary in native node.js addons?

Tags: node.js

In the Node.js v6.4.0 documentation on [Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), the functions adhere to the following pattern.

```
void X(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  ...
}
```

So there is no instantiation of a `HandleScope`, as there used to be in prior versions of node.js. There's only one exception, where a `HandleScope scope(isolate)` is done.

Most of the functions do instantiate `Local<...>` handles, so I'd expect a HandleScope to be necessary so garbage collection is done on function return.

So: When are HandleScopes necessary in node.js 6.4.0 native addons?

Answer (score 1):

In general you do not need a `HandleScope` if you are calling that function from JavaScript. This is because there is already a (parent) scope that is inherited from your JavaScript call site. As soon as that JavaScript scope gets garbage collected, then any handles that you created in C++ will also get collected because they're attached to that scope.

So adding a `HandleScope` to every function won't hurt anything, it's just that it may impact performance some.

Comment: That would explain why there is a `HandleScope` in that single function in the Addons docs that does not get called from JavaScript... Makes sense.